How to insert rows where there is a change to one column
I have a table of tickets created that looks basically like this:



ID
Created
Status
Insert_date




1
10/30/2024
New
10/31/2024


2
10/31/2024
New
11/01/2024



I am currently exporting data from a Sharepoint list as a .csv and importing the data to a staging table where I want to import "New" records (where the ID for the ticket is not currently in the table).  I also want to import rows where there has been a change to the Status of an existing ticket ID to keep track of changes historically.
So let's say the staging table after an import looks like this



ID
Created
Status




1
10/30/2024
In Progress


2
10/31/2024
New


3
11/02/2024
New



The final table after the insert script runs should look like



ID
Created
Status
Insert_date




1
10/30/2024
New
10/31/2024


1
10/30/2024
In Progress
11/02/2024


2
10/31/2024
New
11/01/2024


3
11/02/2024
New
11/02/2024



Now there should be two rows for ticket ID 1 since there was a change, and a new row for ticket ID 3. No changes to ticket ID 2 so no new rows. 11/02/2024 being today's date. The primary key is a combo of ID and Status.
I know how to insert a new ID by doing a left join of the final table with the staging table
INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (ID, Created, Status, Insert_date) 
    SELECT b.ID, b.Created, b.Status, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
    FROM dbo.Tickets_Staging b
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Tickets a ON b.ID = a.ID
    WHERE a.ID IS NULL

However I am stuck as to how to also insert rows where there was a change in Status to the Ticket like there was for ticket ID 1.

Your query is simplified to bring in all records that do not match existing ID+Status combos.
INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (ID,Created,Status,Insert_date) 
SELECT b.ID,b.Created,b.Status,CAST(GETDATE() as date)
FROM dbo.Tickets_Staging b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT * 
                  FROM Tickets a 
                  WHERE b.ID=a.ID AND b.Status=a.Status
                 )

fiddle



ID
Created
Status
Insert_date




1
10/30/2024
New
10/31/2024


1
10/30/2024
In Progress
2024-11-06


2
10/31/2024
New
11/01/2024


3
11/02/2024
New
2024-11-06



This may also work but not as fast:
INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (ID,Created,Status,Insert_date) 
SELECT b.ID,b.Created,b.Status,CAST(GETDATE() as date)
FROM dbo.Tickets_Staging b
LEFT JOIN dbo.Tickets a ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.Status=a.Status
WHERE a.ID IS NULL

see also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists

See the example using MERGE.
This operation is probably redundant for your question.
However, it shows an example of how you can change and/or add rows with a single query.
This operation (MERGE) makes it easier to keep the two data sources consistent.
If necessary, the WHEN MATCHED fragment can be completely removed.
Tickets



ID
Created
Status
Insert_date




1
2024-10-30
New
2024-10-31


2
2024-10-31
New
2024-11-01



Staging



ID
Created
Status




1
2024-10-30
In Progress


2
2024-10-31
New


3
2024-11-02
New



merge tickets as trg
using staging as src
  on src.id=trg.id and src.status=trg.status
when matched  then
  update set created=src.created -- any other column updates : insert_date=src.insert_date
when not matched then
  insert (id,created,status,insert_date)
  values(src.id,src.created,src.status,CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
;




ID
Created
Status
Insert_date




1
2024-10-30
New
2024-10-31


1
2024-10-30
In Progress
2024-11-06


2
2024-10-31
New
2024-11-01


3
2024-11-02
New
2024-11-06



fiddle
